# Problema al intentar que se repita acción cada x tiempo con pygame.time.set_timer()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Estoy programando un juego del tipo "snake" con PygGame en Python. Quiero que mi personaje, llamado "alien", aparezca a la pantalla cada 5 segundos. He utilizado la instrucción  `pygame.time.set_timer()`, pero no funciona. Aquí tenéis mi código:

```
class Alien:

    def __init__(self,image_alien):
        self.ali_x= randint(1,608)
        self.ali_y = randint(1,448)
        self.image_ali=pygame.image.load(image_alien).convert_alpha()

    def nuevo_alien(self):
        self.ali_x= randint(1,608)
        self.ali_y = randint(1,448)

def crear_alien():
    ali=Alien("alien_araignee.png")
    ali.nuevo_alien()
    fenetre.blit(ali.image_ali, (ali.ali_x, ali.ali_y))
    pygame.display.flip()

while True:

juego=1

    while juego:
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)


        for event in pygame.event.get():


            if event.type==QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()

            if event.type==KEYDOWN:

            if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
             juego=0
```

He utilizado `USEREVENT+1` como evento:

```
    if event.type==USEREVENT+1:
        crear_alien()

    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1,5000)
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar, por favor?

Comment: Una duda, ¿Con "aparezca a la pantalla cada 5 segundos" quieres decir que un solo "alien" cambie a una  posición aleatoria  cada 5 segundos, a que cada 5 segundos aparezca un nuevo "alien" en una posición aleatoria manteniendo los anteriores donde estaban o a que cada 5 segundos aparezca fugazmente (aparezca y poco después desaparezca, esperando 5 segundos para volver a aparecer en otro lugar)?